# Python / graphics.py - Points on a circle, looking to stop object from being drawn if outside the drawing area?

Tags: python, graphics, geometry, zelle-graphics

[image]

I am creating a simple drawing program using Zelle's graphics.py in Python

I have a rectangular drawing area and I am trying to get my drawing to stay within the confines of the rectangle without overlap.  One of the challenges is that any drawn object is close to the line of the boundaries of the rectangle (although not technically not outside the drawing area) will draw anyway and cause overlap (see attached image)

Here is what I worked on
(NOTE : I have not included this practice code because it is included in the main code):

PRACTICE and TESTING

- I researched the formula for determining all the points on the circumference of a circle
- Included the formula in a "for loop" to check through all 360 points
- Using test code program, I plotted out the points to ensure the formula worked properly and it drew a circle with all 360 points.  A working model is complete.

I then took the formula into my drawing program to test if it would work.  Right away, I had to use a clone() for the circle because the "for loop" was drawing the same object in the same place over and over giving an error.

After that was fixed, I still could not get the "for loop" and circle formula  to work for me.  I then thought about removing all items from the win.items[:] list ***IF the drawing was outside of the boundary of the rectangle***.  I tried this and still could not get it to work.  Here is the code of the attempt.

```
from graphics import *
import random
import math
win = GraphWin("DRAG", 500, 500)
win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)
drawrect=Rectangle(Point(50,50),Point(450,300))
drawrect.setFill("white")
drawrect.draw(win)
testlist=[]

def motion(event):
    global radius
    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    if (x1 > 50 and x1 < 450) and (y1 > 50 and y1 < 300):
        circ = Circle(Point(x1, y1), radius)
        circ.setFill("black")
        circ1 = circ.clone()
        cx = circ.getCenter().getX()
        cy = circ.getCenter().getY()
        for i in range(0, 360):
            x = radius * math.cos(i) + cx
            y = radius * math.sin(i) + cy
            if (x > 50 and x < 450) and (y > 50 and y < 300):
                circ1 = circ.clone()
                circ1.draw(win)
                print("drawing")
            else:
                circ1 = circ.clone()
                testlist.append(circ1)
                print(testlist)
                print(win.items)
                for item in win.items[1:]:
                    print("This is ITEM in win.items list:", item)
                    if item in testlist:
                        input("YES -  input waiting for enter")
                        for i in win.items[1:]:
                            circ.undraw()
                            circ1.undraw()
                            win.update()
                    else:
                        input("NO  -  input waiting for enter")
radius = 40
win.bind('<B1-Motion>', motion)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: not ideal idea: use widget `Canvas` for drawing place - anddraw on this canvas. It will show only elements in its area and crop rest. But it needs to access `tkinter`. And this canvas still will have full circle but it will only display croped.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem. Do you want to crop circle or remove full circle?

Comment: Remove the circle if it overlaps - no need to crop.  Only full circles drawn within the rectangle would remain

Answer (score 1):

If you want only full circles then you need only

```
    if (50+radius < x1 < 450-radius) and (50+radius < y1 < 300-radius):
```

like

```
def motion(event):

    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    
    if (50+radius < x1 < 450-radius) and (50+radius < y1 < 300-radius):
        circ = Circle(Point(x1, y1), radius)
        circ.setFill("black")
        circ.draw(win)
```

---

Full code:

```
from graphics import *

# --- functions ---

def motion(event):

    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    
    if (50+radius < x1 < 450-radius) and (50+radius < y1 < 300-radius):
        circ = Circle(Point(x1, y1), radius)
        circ.setFill("black")
        circ.draw(win)
        
# --- main ---

radius = 40

win = GraphWin("DRAG", 500, 500)
#win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)

drawrect = Rectangle(Point(50, 50), Point(450, 300))
drawrect.setFill("white")
drawrect.draw(win)

win.bind('<B1-Motion>', motion)

win.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you would to crop circles then it would be problem.

My first idea was to use directly `tkinter.Canvas()` and it will crop elements. But it would need to write all code for drawing `Circle`  and other objects.

So I took code from `GraphicWin()` which is `tkinter.Canvas()` with all functions to draw `Circle` and other objects and little modify - and now you can put in window similar to other objects.

[image]

```
from graphics import *

# --- functions ---

class Canvas(GraphWin):

    """A GraphWin is a toplevel window for displaying graphics."""

    def __init__(self, master, x, y, width=200, height=200, autoflush=True, **kwarg):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, master, width=width, height=height,
                           highlightthickness=0, bd=0,  **kwarg)
        
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
        #self.foreground = "black"
        self.items = []
        self.mouseX = None
        self.mouseY = None
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self._onClick)
        self.bind_all("<Key>", self._onKey)
        self.height = int(height)
        self.width = int(width)
        self.autoflush = autoflush
        self._mouseCallback = None
        self.trans = None
        self.closed = False

        self.lastKey = ""
        if autoflush: update()   # it needs to use `import *`

    def draw(self, canvas):
        self.id = canvas.create_window((self.x, self.y), window=self._w, anchor='nw')
        
# --- functions ---

def motion1(event):
    
    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    
    circ = Circle(Point(x1, y1), radius)
    circ.setFill("black")
    #circ.setOutline("red")
    circ.draw(canvas1)

def motion2(event):
    
    x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
    
    circ = Circle(Point(x1, y1), radius)
    circ.setFill("red")
    circ.setOutline("red")
    circ.draw(canvas2)

# --- main ---

radius = 40

win = GraphWin("DRAG", 500, 700)
#win.master.attributes('-topmost', True)

# Canvas(win, x, y, width, height, ...)
canvas1 = Canvas(win, 50, 50, 400, 250, bg='white')
canvas1.draw(win)
canvas1.bind('<B1-Motion>', motion1)

canvas2 = Canvas(win, 50, 350, 400, 250, bg='white')
canvas2.draw(win)
canvas2.bind('<B1-Motion>', motion2)

# draw on canvas
r = Rectangle(Point(100, 100), Point(150, 150))
r.setFill('red')
r.setOutline("red")
r.draw(canvas1)

win.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

This better shows that circles are croped.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response.  Someone just told me about a solution using the radius that is almost exactly the same as yours.  I was making it needlessly complicated so again, thank you for taking the time.  If I wanted to crop, it would be easier to redraw the frame around the rectangle each time rather than try and sort out part of a circle.